# How to stop mongod after "unkown instance" error

Tags: mongodb, service, ubuntu-14.04

After running two mongodb instance, I can't stop mongod service. After executing:

```
$ sudo service mongod stop
Stop: Unkown instance
```

I know that this question have been asked but they are looking for how to avoid this error and I am looking for how to actually stop the `mongod` service after getting this error...

Comment: How did you start the second instance?

Comment: first and second instance: `sudo service mongod start`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `sudo service mongod start` twice doesn't start mongo twice. It should be an idempotent operation meaning it only has an effect the first time if mongo wasn't running. Any attempts to start it afterwards will do nothing.

Your message of `Stop: Unkown instance` will mean that it couldn't find any running Mongo processes to stop.

To verify Mongo isn't running, try running

```
 sudo ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongo
```

If that returns nothing, then you don't have any mongo processes running.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just kill the process. Works every time.

```sh
killall -9 mongod
```